# Dynamically pulling images from XML for iPhone App

Tags: xml, iphone

I've got my iPhone app pulling down live data content via XML nicely, and I've formatted the UITableView cells to display the content without too many headaches.

However, at the moment, for each cell I'm just showing a default graphic for now, but I want this to be pulled down from my server too.

The code snippet that grabs the image (which is actually in my project) is:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TBC.png"];
```

But that will need to be the dynamic image.

In my XML, am I better just returning 'mypic.png' and let the SDK determine the full path, like http://myapp.com/mypic.png or storing the full URL to the image in the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is storing the image locally and the XML just tells the app what image to use, then use just the file name.

Comment: yeah I thought that might be the easiest way. it's a tricky one to get right