# how to change images in iphone app dynamically through XML file

Tags: iphone, ios

My app contains some images which needs to be dynamically loaded from web server through XML file. Every time when changes done in admin console at web server it should reflect in iPhone app too through the XML file. I wrote XML file but dont know how to get used in iPhone code. I referred the following links,

[how-to-retrieve-data-through-xml-in-iphone-locally-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596451/how-to-retrieve-data-through-xml-in-iphone-locally-file)

[dynamically-pulling-images-from-xml-for-iphone-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465975/dynamically-pulling-images-from-xml-for-iphone-app)

[how-to-change-the-tabbaritem-images-dynamically-in-iphone-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193929/how-to-change-the-tabbaritem-images-dynamically-in-iphone-app)

[retrieving-images-to-iphone-app-through-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397649/retrieving-images-to-iphone-app-through-xml)

but all these links are not clear for me to understand. Kindly suggest me a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume your web server can serve an XML which includes the image in some encoded format like base64. Then you need to:

1. Load the file. For this, you should use `NSURLConnection`, e.g. as described in [how-to-make-http-request-from-iphone-and-parse-json-result](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/how-to-make-http-request-from-iphone-and-parse-json-result/)
2. Parse the XML. Instead of parsing a JSON, you need to parse your XML, so first, you need an XML-parser. [Here is a comparison of XML parsers](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project). Then you should access the element in the XML that represents your image. This step depends on your choice of the parser.
3. Decode the Image. Your element is probably an `NSString` and you want to have its binary representation as `NSData`. `NSData` has some convenience functions for this. E.g. for base64, there is the `dataFromBase64String:` constructor.
4. Create the image. That is,  `UIImage` using the `imageWithData:` constructor.
5. Display the image. You need an `UIImageView` and assign to it your `UIImage`. Set the frame of the view and add it to your preferred subview.

It is also possible that the XML provides URLs where to get the image data. Then you have to do a new request. This should be clear by now, how to do.

Good luck.

Comment: i can understand the points 1, 2 , 4 & 5 what exactly i want to do, but in 3rd you had mentioned about decoding image am not understanding how to do it can you elaborate it. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: image is typically a jpeg, which is binary data in a file. If you want to stuff the image into the XML, which is one common practice, then it has to be text encoded. The most common encoding for this is base64. So the image binary data is converted to base64 text. The other, even more common practice is, if the XML provides a link, an URL to the image. Then just fetch it as you did with the XML and you already should have an `NSData` you can stuff into your `UIImage`.

Comment: That's cool ! now i got clear how to proceed from 1 to 5 points. Thank you so much ilmiacs..